# How to delete all the files matching regular expression in elisp?

Tags: regular-expressions, files, deletion

I want to make some clean-up with auto-generated files. How can I delete all the files matching some regexp mask from within elisp?
As an example of desired functionality... Something like the line below:

```
(delete-file "*.txt")
```

should delete all the text files in the current working directory...

Comment: <https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info>

Answer (score 1):

```lisp
(dolist (filename (directory-files "working-dir"))
  (when (string-match-p "\\.txt\\'" filename)
    (delete-file (file-name-concat "working-dir" filename))))
```

Comment: Or use `dired`?

Comment: @FranBurstall: I'm not familiar with `dired`.  Maybe you can write an answer that uses `dired`, if you're familiar with it.

Comment: You can use a `match` argument in `directory-files` and avoid the explicit `string-match`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dired` as @FranBurstall suggested in a comment: use `C-x C-f` (`find-file`) on the directory, mark files for deletion with `% d` (`dired-flag-files`) followed by some regexp (e.g. `.*\.txt$` - note that this is a regexp, *not* a glob and it specifies files whose names end with `.txt`), then after looking to make sure that you've got all the files you want and *only* those, press `x` to execute the deletions. Otherwise, press `U` to unmark everything and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly improved version of shynur's snippet, that covers my needs. I've included NickD's comment and also replaced `file-name-concat` with `concat` since the former is not present in my Emacs version (27.1):

```
(defun my/delete-regexped-files (mask)
  ;; Delete all the files in the current directory that
  ;; match given regular expression.
  ;; Examples of mask: "\\.org~\\'", "\\.txt\\'"

(dolist (filename (directory-files "" nil mask) )
   (delete-file  filename )))
```